# .htaccess too many redirects. Redirect all users except ip to different part of website

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to make a website where all users are redirected to a specific part in the domain so that they can see a "comming soon" page. While some ip addresses can still access the normal website so that they can see how it is going to look.

What I'm trying to do: create a wordpress website in the root of public_html, create a soon directory in public_html and redirect all users except a few ip's to http://www.domain.com/soon/index.html

My .htaccess looks as followed:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^1.2.3.4
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/soon/index.html [R=302,L]
```

However whenever I go to the website to test it out it tells me:
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Is there something I'm doing wrong in my .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this rule as your **very first rule** in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(1\.2\.3\.4|11\.22\.33\.44)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js)$
RewriteRule !^soon/index\.html$ http://www.domain.com/soon/index.html [R=302,L,NC]
```

- Variable `REMOTE_ADDR` matches client's IP in a web request.
- `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is needed to avoid redirecting for css/js/image files and `/soon/index.html` file.

Comment: It seems like this does redirect me to the right page but so did my original one and I'm still getting the same ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. Perhaps it gets stuck in a loop because it tries to redirect on the same domain that it's already in and causes /soon/index.html to redirect again and again.

Comment: hmm I just tested whether it doesn't redirect me if I put in my ip address with an or statement in the RewriteCond rule like so:
`RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=1.2.3.4 [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=5.6.7.8`
for some reason it still redirects me even though my correct ip address is in there...

Comment: Okay it seems that the [OR] condition doesn't work, when I put my ip address in the first RewriteCond it does work. Do you have any idea how I can have several ip addresses specified in there that are able to view the website normally?

Comment: Another thing is that whenever I go to a different page then http://www.domain.com it doesn't redirect the page, so someone sketchy might do: http://www.domain.com/wp-login.php and actually get to the wordpress login page instead of the redirected page.

Comment: I'll try it out tomorrow, I just got home from work and I forgot the ftp access it's saved in filezilla on work so I have to wait until tomorrow. Also, does this mean I can add php to the request uri? So that it also redirects when users try to access specific php files? If so that's pretty awesome :)

Comment: My modified rule will also redirect all `*.php` files to `/soon/index.html`. Feel free to leave a comment here whenever you get a chance to test this rule further and I will respond.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.2\.3\.4$
RewriteRule .? /soon/index.html [L]
```

Comment: When using this .htaccess I'm getting an internal server error 500. Not sure why? Should I perhaps remove the slashes in front of the ip address? I'm also uploading my wordpress site to the root directory as we speak so I'm not sure if this causes the problem to exist. I did however change my .htaccess back to the original one and the internal server error is gone but I do still get the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS then...

Comment: add the dollar sign to the end in line RewriteCond, and check again.

Comment: Still gives me an internal server error. The answer I got from anubhava seems to be working but it also redirects for the specified ip addresses. Perhaps the internal server error has something to do with not recognizing /soon/index.html as a base directory structure? Perhaps it looks in the root instead of the public_html? I'm not sure, I'm rather unfamillair with .htaccess...